# How to show the category name for each articles?

Tags: laravel

I use many-to-many relation.

It is necessary to list the articles to which categories the post belongs, I did this with the help of the builder, since I do not know how to do this, via ORM.

I have three tables:

**categories**
-id
-name

**images**
-id
-image
-description

**category_image (pivot table)**
-id
-image_id
-category_id

```
public function getCategoryTitle($id)
    {  
        $post = DB::table('category_image')
                     ->where('image_id', '=', $id)
                     ->get();
        $categoryImage = $post->toArray()[0]->category_id;

        $showCategory = DB::table('categories')
                     ->where('id', '=', $categoryImage)
                     ->get();

       return $showCategory->toArray()[0]->name;

    }
```

Now it turns out that for each article, there will be 2 more requests to the database, which is very bad.

output so

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Image::all();

        return view('admin.posts.index', ['posts'=>$posts]);
    }
```

---

I tried to get categories name with ->

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <tr>
      <td>{{$post->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$post->description}}</td>
      <td>{{$post->getCategoryTitle($post->id)}}</td>
  <tr>
@endforeach
```

**Image model**

```
dd( $this->belongsToMany(
            Category::class,
            'category_image',
            'image_id',
            'category_id',
                1
        ));
```

Is there any easy way to get category name for each image using relation.

Comment: are you want to show category name for each images ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**in image model**

```
public function categories(){
 return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)
}
```

**in category model**

```
public function images(){
 return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class)
}
```

`with()` for eager loading, provides you to get categories in single query

```
$posts = Image::with("categories")->get();

foreach($posts as $post) {
  foreach ($post->categories as $category){
     $category->name
   }
}
```

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all does not exist.

Comment: replaced with get () and earned

Comment: @DivMan Ops, sorry I forgot change, it should be get(), I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

If your relationships are set up correctly with laravel you can use the shorthand ->with('categories') (name dependin on the name of your belongs to many function in your class) to grab the category row as well